# how sort & display data?

Tags: php, xml

I have this code from a weather report

```
$url = ('https://www.yr.no/sted/Norge/Vestland/Bergen/Bergen/varsel.xml');

    $feed = simplexml_load_file($url) or die('Can not connect to server');
    $result = array();
    foreach ($feed->forecast->tabular->time as $content) {
        array_push($result, [ "from" => (string)$content['from'],
            "to" => (string)$content['to'],
            'symbol' => (string)$content->symbol['name'],
            'temperature' => (string)$content->temperature['value'],
            'windDirection' => (string)$content->windDirection['code'],
            'windSpeed' => (string)$content->windSpeed['mps'],
        ]);
    }
print_r($result)
```

printing an array

Example output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [from] => 2020-02-02T21:00:00 [to] => 2020-02-03T00:00:00 [symbol] => Lettskyet [temperature] => 2 [windDirection] => ENE [windSpeed] => 2.0 ) [1] => Array ( [from] => 2020-02-03T00:00:00 [to] => 2020-02-03T06:00:00 [symbol] => Skyet [temperature] => 1 [windDirection] => E [windSpeed] => 2.1 ) [2] => Array ( [from] => 2020-02-03T06:00:00 [to] => 2020-02-03T12:00:00 [symbol] => Skyet [temperature] => 1 [windDirection] => E [windSpeed] => 2.4 )
```

How could I sort this data in a minimal and modern way? 
maybe something like this:
[image]

I am quite unexperienced. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use table something like this. Just example:

```
    <?php
    $url = ('https://www.yr.no/sted/Norge/Vestland/Bergen/Bergen/varsel.xml');

        $feed = simplexml_load_file($url) or die('Can not connect to server');
        $result = array();
        foreach ($feed->forecast->tabular->time as $content) {
            array_push($result, [ "from" => (string)$content['from'],
                "to" => (string)$content['to'],
                'symbol' => (string)$content->symbol['name'],
                'temperature' => (string)$content->temperature['value'],
                'windDirection' => (string)$content->windDirection['code'],
                'windSpeed' => (string)$content->windSpeed['mps'],
            ]);
        }

    ?>
    <table border=1 cellpadding=5 style=" background:blue; color: #fff;">
    <?php foreach ($result as $value) { ?>
    <tr><td>Bergen <br /><?php echo $value['from'] ?> to  <?php echo $value['to'] ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $value['symbol'] ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $value['temperature'] ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $value['windDirection'] ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $value['windSpeed'] ?></td></tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```